# PHP Form Submits But Only Updates Last Row.. Need to Update All Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that is populated by this query.  This works fine and I have the values in the appropriate text fields.  Here is the form code:

```
print "<form action='update.php' method='post'>";

print "<table width='655' border='1'><tr><th width='40'>Quantity</th><th width='40'>Code</th><th width='175'>Product Description</th><th width='50'>Unit Price</th><th width='50'>Total Price</th><th width='50'>Qty Checked</th><th width='65'>Quantity Passed</th><th width='65'>Failure Type</th>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_po WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<td>" . $row['QTY'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='ID[]' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['CODE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['UNIT_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['TOTAL_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='QTY_CHECKED[]' style='padding:5px;' value='" . $row['QTY_CHECKED'] . "'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='QTY_PASSED[]' style='padding:5px;' value='" . $row['QTY_PASSED'] . "'></td>";
echo "<td><select name='FAILURE_TYPE[]'><option value=''></option><option value='Missing'>Missing</option><option value='Option 2'>Option 2</option></select></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

print "<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Click to Save'></p><p><strong>Comments</strong></p>";
```

It then gets passed to my update which looks like the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$sql = "UPDATE b_tasks_po SET QTY_CHECKED='".$_POST['QTY_CHECKED']."', QTY_PASSED='".$_POST['QTY_PASSED']."', FAILURE_TYPE='".$_POST['FAILURE_TYPE']."' WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID']."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or 
die ("Error"); }
```

The first query which displays all the appropriate rows in the database returns 7 rows.  There are form elements on each row.  I currently want to update the numbers in each row, press submit and then it update them in the database.  Currently the issue is that it only updates the last row.  I understand after reading that it is recognising all the same field names but I've added [] to the end of each name but still no joy.

Each row in the table has an ID and I have a hidden text field which identifies the ID in each row, so where am I going wrong?  Why is it just updating the last row?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what echo `var_dump($_POST['QTY_CHECKED'])`. returned:

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(5) "25000" [2]=> string(2) "25" [3]=> string(2) "15" [4]=> string(2) "25" [5]=> string(2) "54" [6]=> string(6) "120000" }
```

Comment: Please try to refrain from using the `mysql_*` functions as they are now deprecated. Instead, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php (PDO) or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php (MySQLi)

Comment: Could we get a var_dump of the $_POST?

Comment: Added a var_dump of the $_POST['QTY_CHECKED'] in the section above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form data is an array of arrays but you aren't looping through them. Your save code should look like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['ID'] as $index => $id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE b_tasks_po SET QTY_CHECKED='".$_POST['QTY_CHECKED'][$index]."', QTY_PASSED='".$_POST['QTY_PASSED'][$index]."', FAILURE_TYPE='".$_POST['FAILURE_TYPE'][$index]."' WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID'][$index]."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql)or 
    die ("Error"); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy you have to run your query in loop, try something like below code.

```
$count = count($_POST['ID']);
if($count>0){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
   $sql = "UPDATE b_tasks_po SET QTY_CHECKED='".$_POST['QTY_CHECKED'][$i]."', QTY_PASSED='".$_POST['QTY_PASSED'][$i]."', FAILURE_TYPE='".$_POST['FAILURE_TYPE'][$i]."' WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID'][$i]."'";
   $result=mysql_query($sql)or die ("Error"); 
 }
}
```